# audio.play() is not a function.

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing this Javascript (vanilla JS) 30 days challenge by  http://wesbos.com. 
and im trying not to look at the reference code for the first challenge.

Any way, I am trying to make this code work, but i eventually get this error : " **Uncaught TypeError: audElem.play is not a function** "

This is my code :

```
function functionA( item){

  //  alert("HEYYY")
  item.classList.add("playing");

  var audElem= item.getElementsByTagName('audio') [0].getElementsByTagName('source')[0];

  var song= audElem.getAttribute('src');
  song.currentTime=0;
  song.play();
}
```

And this the html part:

```
<li class="flex-item " > A  

  <span class="flex-SubItem"> <br />  BOOM </span> 

  <audio id="boom" >
   <source src="sound-effects/boom.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
</li>
```

I tried to figured it out but nothing. I have no one to ask but you guys. 
I hope i get answers.
thank any way :)

Answer (score 7):

`play` is a method of the `<audio>` object but you are calling it on a *string* that you get from an attribute of the `<source>` object.

Comment: Exactly. <audio> is basically the player which has all the methods to control him. the <source> object just tells the "player" where to get its data

Comment: Hello: and thx fir responding guys. 
Any way you could tell me how i can fix it? 
Because i really have tried everything ( i khnow), and i was using 
    <audio src=""> </audio> before using it with <source>  but nothing seemed to work. 
thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

For who ever is interested i finally managed to make it work by getting the id of the audio tag and call it after that. 
here's the code:

```
             function functionA( item){

             item.classList.add("playing");

            var audElem= item.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].getAttribute('id');

             var song = document.getElementById(audElem);
             song.play();

         }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just fixed it using querySelector. In your case, you can replace the code below:

```
var audElem= item.getElementsByTagName('audio') [0].getElementsByTagName('source')[0];
var song= audElem.getAttribute('src');
```

with this single line here:

```
document.querySelector('boom').play();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `play()` on the audio element.

```
  document.getElementById('boom').play();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g5d0a6Lg/

Comment: What is the point of that IIFE? There are not local variables to limit the scope of.

Comment: hey Stefano :) 
Thank you! But i actually have muliple <li> so i dont want to access it by the ID. ( i dont khnow if waht i said is clear) 

Ps: (the song  you chose is great ;) )

Comment: basically none. i would like to implement his function passing the variabile he is using to add the item from outside but at the end i didn't.

Comment: so you have multiple li and inside each of them you have audio element?

Comment: @StefanoCerelli exactly

Comment: @olfaDhaouadi so what do you want to achive? Click on LI and play the audio?

Comment: @StefanoCerelli well according to the challenge im making : 
on " hover " the <li> has to transition(css prop) and play an audio.

Comment: @olfaDhaouadi and you're not using any external library right?

Comment: @StefanoCerelli no im not and should not. the purpose here is to only use  "pure Javascript" if im saying it right