# issue with sending event data with click over socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, amazon-web-services, socket.io

Forgive me, I've been learning node and js over the last few days, come from C#/unity and everything is a little bit different from what I know. I'm making a collaborative drum machine, I've got 90% working: http://ec2-54-194-29-66.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9000/

I have the node server working, with key presses being sent and mouse co-ords, however I have an issue with mapping a mouse click event, I am registering the click in console of other connections and server, but seems I don't quite understand sending the contents  of events properly. I can't write var data = list: e.classList and read data.list to do the see the same thing?

Here's code I've been trying to get working, but I get cannot read property error:

```
    function newMouseOn(data)
    {
        console.log("Is this working Click On?" + data.target);
        data.list.add('active');
        //clickPlayOn(data);
        data.target.play();
    }

    function newMouseOff(data)
    {
        console.log("Is this working ClickOff?" + data.target);
        //clickPlayOff(data);
        data.list.remove('active');
    }   

socket.on('mouseOn', newMouseOn);
socket.on('mouseOff', newMouseOff);


  function clickPlayOn(e)
    {
       var data = {
         id: e.target.id,
         timeStamp: e.timeStamp,
         type: e.type,
         target: e.target,
         list: e.classList
       }
        socket.emit('mouseOn', data);
        e.target.classList.add('active');
        e.target.play();
    }

    function clickPlayOff(e)
    {
      var data =
      {
        id: e.target.id,
        timeStamp: e.timeStamp,
        type: e.type,
        target: e.target,
        list: e.classList
        }
        socket.emit('mouseOff', data);
        e.target.classList.remove('active');
    }


server side: 

  socket.on('mouseOn', MouseClick);
  socket.on('mouseOff', MouseClicked);


function MouseClick(data)
  {
    socket.broadcast.emit('mouseOn', data);
    console.log(data);
  }

  function MouseClicked(data)
  {
    socket.broadcast.emit('mouseOff', data);
    console.log(data);
  }
```

I was originally trying to just emit e or e.target instead of that data struct, but that didn't seem to work. Has anyone got any ideas on what I'm missing? (other than a brain)

Answer (score 1):

the object you received (`data`) has no methods, it is transferred as JSON and then converted to object, so you can not to invoke any methods like `data.target.play();`.

if you need any methods you have to add them when the object is received.

Comment: ok I think I got you, it's just sending a bunch of text and no methods of what to do. so I instead go: btn[e.target.id].classList.add('active');
                        btn[e.target.id].play();

and my buttons are set up: 

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('mousedown', clickPlayOn);
  btn[i].addEventListener('mouseup', clickPlayOff); // emit here?
}

I think I'm still a bit confused where to emit from, should I do it from the code above? I think I'm gonna create a feedback loop if i'm not careful!

Comment: sorry, I did not go deep into the rest of your code,
anyway, you need to transfer a data to understand what to play at the other client-side, like id of buttons, or sounds etc.
I think no loops are possible if you are emitting from `clickPlayOn` and receiving it in `newMouseOn`

Comment: I've been trying that, sending the button id over as well in the ClickPlayOn, part, I want to just add the index of the button something like `btn[i].addEventListener('mousedown', clickPlayOn(index: i));`

can I add an index along inside that (e) event function, normally it's like `clickPlayOn()` above but the function has clickPlayOn(e), I take it e is event, can I chuck things on to it? what's the syntax, i'm getting something about missing ) after argument list, when experimenting with the bit above. Thanks for your help btw, really kind of you.

Comment: I'm not sure that using the `i` as the `id` is good idea. You can add any custom id as an attribute to the html, like

`<button data-sound="sound_1" ...`

and to use it instead of `i`. to get it on a click you can do something like this: 

`e.target.getAttribute('data-sound')`

but I'm not sure about the exact syntax

Comment: ok thanks, I'm not sure that's the best way, as i need to trigger off visuals for buttons as well, and thought if I just knew the exact button, or could keep track off it as in integer it would make my life easier.

<div class="button" data-key="q" data-sound="audio/kick.mp3"></div>

could I write an id for the button there? data-id = "1" for example?

I've tried your way and I can get the name of the sound over, still can't just .play() it, I don't know where that function comes from, is it part of eventlistener? i don't know why I'm struggling with this, I've got the keys done

Comment: this is whole thing btw: https://github.com/richhop/socket_test/blob/master/public/index.html

Comment: I have the file audio file name printed in console, but I get errors wihen trying to play it:

var soundFile = e;

document.getElementById(soundFile).play();

I've followed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767537/audio-play-is-not-a-function I'm just getting confused as to why it's not working.

Comment: I was being a damn idiot, I should have followed what i said earlier, ended up naming the buttons data-id="1" data-id="2" etc,  and then using the same as I would before, I just thought the buttons would have an auto-assigned integer id I could read.